# How can I choose the resistors for a push-pull class AB amplifier (diode biasing) to get a certain bias current?

Tags: diodes, bjt, bias, push-pull, power-amplifier

[image]

Hello guys, this is my very first question.

This is a part from a BJt audio amplifier volume control with 3 stages (Pre-amplifier,Buffer, & Power amplifier). This is the power amplifier stage.

I am asked to design the resistors RB3b & RB3a to provide a bias current of Ic=(375/20) mA when the input and output terminals are open circuits and to get Rin.

I proceeded in the problem,The voltage drop between the two diodes is 1.4V so I found that the voltage drop between each resistor is 3.8V and Vce for each transistor is 4.5V.

The problem is I cannot find beta (current gain) from the data sheet to deduce Ib and the current in the resistors.
the date sheet provide beta for maximum of Vce=1V so I am stuck.

plus I read that the current in the resistors should be 10 Ib, is that right?
I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Job interview? Or classwork? This cannot possibly be a realistic design question.

Comment: @jonk class project, can you help ?

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the schematic? Or are you absolutely stuck with that crap?

Comment: @jonk  I am certainly stuck

Comment: What's the worst-case peak-to-peak range of the signal driving this stage? (Hopefully, as close to zero as possible. This output stage topology works best when there's no signal.)

Comment: @jonk 
 Yes, there is no signal 
this is a large signal analysis so the capacitors at the input and output terminals are open circuits.

Comment: Cool!! Then that simplifies things a lot. So, are you allowed to modify the \$500\:\text{m}\Omega\$ emitter degeneration resistors?

Comment: @jonk not I cannot modify the original design

Comment: So you are only allowed to modify the two resistors, which probably should be of identical value, yes? You get to calculate exactly one value. That's all? Sorry to ask so many questions but I keep prodding for something as yet unsaid. It's possible to set the collector current with some possibility of being close, if you are allowed to modify the emitter resistors. But you can't.

Comment: @jonk  I am given the collector current, it is to be (375/20) mA
I need to calculate the  identical resistors to get this value

Comment: Start between the two 1N4148 diodes. Call it 0 V. Move up through the top diode to the base of \$Q_3\$. What's the voltage there?$$V_\text{B}=0\:\text{V}+\eta_{_D}\,V_T\,\ln\left(1+\frac{I_D}{I_\text{SAT}}\right)$$Now, subtracting the base-emitter voltage for \$Q_3\$ gives the voltage across the \$500\:\text{m}\Omega\$ resistor, so we can say that:$$I_{C_\text{Q3}}\cdot 500\:\text{m}\Omega=\eta_{_D}\,V_T\,\ln\left(1+\frac{I_D}{I_{\text{SAT}_\text{D}}}\right)-\eta_{_\text{Q3}}\,V_T\,\ln\left(1+\frac{I_{C_\text{Q3}}}{I_{\text{SAT}_\text{Q3}}}\right)$$ Make sense so far?

Comment: Ok but I already have a zero ground reference so I can't assume that the point between the diode is 0V. This is an open circuit not a zero input voltage @jonk

Comment: You can make any assignment to a node that you want to, for working the loop. There's no conflict so long as we are speaking relatively through a loop. That said, you can work through the KVL from 9 V down to 0 V, through the two resistors and the two diodes. It should be 4.5 V there if you assume the resistors are the same value and the diodes are identical. The same will also be true, using other KVL to reach through the emitter paths. So the above point remains. The voltage between the diodes is equal to the voltage between the emitter resistors.

Comment: @jonk ok continue please

Comment: Well, there's a huge problem with this assigned task. You don't get to "just set" the quiescent collector current for the BJTs. You could (mostly), if you were allowed to change the emitter resistors. But without that and at 18.75 mA, the resistors' drops are each less than 10 mV. So, 20 mV between the emitters. This is 10 X too low to do any design without knowing parameter details. Maybe even worse than that.

Comment: Assuming the circuit parameters you've given, which appears to leave out \$\beta\$ so assumed infinite, you have \$V_\text{D}=700\:\text{mV}\$, \$I_\text{C}=18.75\:\text{mA}\$, and therefore \$V_\text{BE}=V_\text{D}-18.75\:\text{mA}\cdot 500\:\text{m}\Omega\approx 691\:\text{mV}\$. This means the voltage across the remaining resistor is, as you say, \$3.8\:\text{V}\$. If we chose a different collector current the only thing that changes is \$V_\text{BE}\$. But without any BJT parameters it doesn't matter. So you get to just pick. There's no argument against a pick, given the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is I cannot find beta (current gain) from the data sheet
>   to deduce Ib and the current in the resistors. the date sheet provide
>   beta for maximum of Vce=1V so I am stuck.

At low Collector current the current gain doesn't vary much above saturation, so you can take the value at 1 V and it should be close enough. The Base-Emitter voltage drop may be more important. Here's a graph of I<sub>C</sub> vs V<sub>BE</sub> from the [Vishay BC337/338 datasheet](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet2/a/0su3121qu41qly40k0chk9q4273y.pdf).

[image]

At 25 °C and I<sub>C</sub> = 20 mA, V<sub>BE</sub> is ~0.65 V. Note the strong temperature dependence. This is why you need to use a diode to set the bias voltage, and it should be thermally coupled to the transistor so their voltages track.